# Float placement, not in the right position

Tags: html, css

i have my main "watchlisten" div, with everything you see so far inside, but for some apparent reason, i am unable to float my video image on the right side of my left arrow image, i have this as the code for CSS and HTML, i apologize for not having the images available for you to see them, but i want to float Video_1.jpg on the right of Left_watchlisten.jpg.

HTML for the whole watchlisten DIV

```
<div id="watchlisten">

                    <img src="Images/boxes.png" class="imageBoxes" />

                    <h2>Watch/Listen</h2>

                    <img src="Images/Left_Watchlisten.jpg" class="leftarrow"/>

                    <div class="wlblock">
                            <img src="Images/Video_1.jpg" height="75"/>
                            <p>action to cut leve crossing deaths</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS code for all the classes/id's/h2.

```
#watchlisten {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    float: right;
    width: 380px;
    position: relative;
    top: -80px;
}

h2 {
    color: #505050;
    margin:  10px 0 10px 10px;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}

.imageBoxes {
    float: right;
    max-height: 20px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 12px 10px 0 0;
}

.leftArrow {
    float: left !important;
    border-right: 1px solid white;

}

.wlblock {
    float: left;

}
```

i hope someone can help, i am a little stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in your class naming

Your CSS code:

```
.leftArrow {
    float: left !important;
    border-right: 1px solid white;

}
```

Your HTML code:

```
 <img src="Images/Left_Watchlisten.jpg" class="leftarrow"/>
```

Can you see the difference in class name?

Make the leftArrow, leftarrow in css or leftarrow in html to leftArrow.

It will work.

Comment: thank you Diwas! that fixed my issue!

Comment: @DanielFormosa  can you accept my answer if it worked?

Comment: i did :3 it wouldnt allow me when you posted it i had to wait then i forgot to do it, but its all good now :3

Comment: thanks @DanielFormosa